# return multiple byte arrays using ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, bytearrayoutputstream

I am struggling to return multiple byte arrays using ByteArrayOutputStream. I have multiple string values that need to be converted to separate byte arrays and then return each one of them. My issue is that toByteArray() method does not work on ByteArrayOutputStream[], compiler shows following error "cannot invoke toByteArray() on the array type ByteArrayOutputStream[]". Here is the code:

```
int Count = getListsize.size(); <--- List has two elements of type String
ByteArrayOutputStream[] baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream[Count];

   for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++) {
        baos[i].write("string".getBytes());
                    
   }
    return baos.toByteArray();   <--- Doesn't work with the ByteArrayOutputStream[]
```

Comment: That's not really what that class is for. If you want to return several different byte arrays why don't you just call `String.getBytes()` however many times you need to?

Comment: very true, issue is we are using ide/libraries from a customer and it has some strange behavior, returning values like String.getBytes() results in crash and no one has figured out why does it happen, that is why resorted to ByteArrayOutputStream which luckily worked . It may sound naive but this is a fix we are in

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `toByteArray()` on each individual `ByteArrayOutputStream` in the array.  You can create your own `byte[][]` to store that in.  That said, of course, the code you've shown us has no reason to use `ByteArrayOutputStream`, since it's just using it to copy the result of `"string".getBytes()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, check my comment above in response to @g00se.  2D byte array should work, will give it a try.